# How to Rotate matrix with setPolyToPoly

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am a newbie to android classes and development. I am working on a canvas image where I do free transformation on the setPolyToPoly. But I want also to make it rotate or scaled and move. I am confuse and know nothing about where to put the code to work.

The situation is. I can move, rotate and scale the image. But when I do transformation and then move the image, the transformation in setPolyToPoly is reset. How to make it not being resetted. Thanks

```
r = new RectF(); 
matrix.mapRect(r);
float[] src2 = new float[] { 
                0, 
                0,
                bitmapFreeTrans.getWidth(), 
                0, 
                bitmapFreeTrans.getWidth(), 
                bitmapFreeTrans.getHeight(), 
                0, 
                bitmapFreeTrans.getHeight() };
        float[] dst2 = new float[] { 
                CIRCLE_TOP_LEFT.x,
                CIRCLE_TOP_LEFT.y,
                CIRCLE_TOP_RIGHT.x, 
                CIRCLE_TOP_RIGHT.y,
                CIRCLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT.x,
                CIRCLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT.y, 
                CIRCLE_BOTTOM_LEFT.x,
                CIRCLE_BOTTOM_LEFT.y 
                };
        canvas.save();
        matrix.setPolyToPoly(src2, 0, dst2, 0, 4);
```

Below is my gesture listener:

```
 SimpleOnMoveGestureListener mgl = new SimpleOnMoveGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
        PointF delta = detector.getFocusDelta();
        matrix.postTranslate(delta.x, delta.y);
        parent.invalidate();
        x1 = delta.x;
        y1 = delta.y;
        return true;
    }
};

SimpleOnScaleGestureListener sgl = new SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
        parent.invalidate();
        // copy values for rotate gesture
        getFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
        getFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
        return true;
    }
};

SimpleOnRotateGestureListener rgl = new SimpleOnRotateGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
        matrix.postRotate(-detector.getRotationDegreesDelta(), getFocusX, getFocusY);  
        parent.invalidate();
        return true;
    };
};
```

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/WmgtS3Vi)

Comment: Thanks @pskink. I'll try it. :)

Comment: Hi @pskink. This code float[] dst = {
                    0, 0, w, h / 4, w, h - h / 4, 0, h. I want to ask what is the reason we divide by 4.? I am confuse :). But the code help me though.

Comment: Just to make perspective effect

Comment: I see. :). I thought it has to do with setPolyToPoly(src2, 0, dst2, 0, 4); the  4 here. anyway. Thanks . I should have read the documentation. But my rotation is not centered although I divide the width and height.  
     matrix.postRotate(+rotation, bitmapFreeTrans.getWidth() / 2, bitmapFreeTrans.getHeight() / 2);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bitmap you can do

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    //Rotates Bitmap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

and you can set your existing Bitmap to it by calling this method like....

```
myBitmap = rotateBitmap(myBitmap, 90);
```

this would rotate it 90 degrees

Comment: I notice this create a new bitmap. But is there a another way that both matrix.setPolyToPoly and matrix.postRotate works. This is what so far i implemented matrix.setPolyToPoly(src2, 0, dst2, 0, 4);
      matrix.postRotate(rotation, getFocusX, getFocusY); But nothing works.